# Why does my python for loop return the same first value X times rather than unique values?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm querying a Postgres database (nfldb for anyone familiar) from Python and would like to make one of my query criteria a variable to streamline my data collection. The code I'm using

```
import nfldb
db = nfldb.connect()
q = nfldb.Query(db)
for i in range (1,15):
    q.game(season_year=2015, season_type='Regular', week=i)
    q.player(full_name='Julian Edelman')
    print p.player.full_name, p.receiving_yds, p.receiving_tds
```

I would expect this to return each week's stats, but it returns the first week's stats 14 times. When I change `week = i` to explicit numbers, it returns the stats as I would expect. Why might this be happening?

Comment: Post the rest of your code.

Comment: whats the p for? what does it calls? shouldnt it be like q.player.full_name, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question here will be difficult for anyone not familiar with `nfldb` to answer because the `.game` nomenclature is a special feature of `nfldb` that can be used to further filter your query `q`.

By narrowing the scope of your query to a single week, you are giving `nfldb` permission to discard all other non-fitting data. So when you repeat your loop and ask for the next week, you are asking for data that you just told `nfldb` to discard from `q`.

If you want to make the same query over each week individually, you will need to tuck your `q = nfldb.Query(db)` into the for loop so as to reset the expectation that the query starts with all data in the database available to it.

```
import nfldb
db = nfldb.connect()
for i in range (1,15):
    q = nfldb.Query(db)
    q.game(season_year=2015, season_type='Regular', week=i)
    q.player(full_name='Julian Edelman')
```

As someone else mentioned, though, you are missing something from this codeblock since `p` appears out of nowhere.

Comment: Thank you for your response.